# Get percentage by category in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-orm

I'm struggling with the ORM, I need to be able to get the percentage of the product(s) per category.

A product has a foreign key of category. The ideal result would be:
Category 1 = 20%
Category 2 = 15.6%

I was able to get the total per category but failed to get the percentage

```
Product.objects.filter(category__isnull=False).annotate(percentage=Count("pk")).order_by("category__name")
```

I might be able to solve this with Subquery but failed on multiple approaches. Any ideas?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19286834/django-calculate-percentage-based-on-object-count this might help you

Comment: that is my first approach but I'm trying to make it more optimized and lessen the number of queries.